# What makes the difference for the genenric type

Tags: java, object, generics

while I was doing my project I faced a new confusion of using generic type which is the subtle change in the object.

Normally, when I construct a node I declared the generic like this

```
public class HW3<E> {
    private Tree<E> treeNode = new Tree <E> ();
```

But now if I do it like this this appears as normal too.

```
public class HW3<E> {
    private Tree<Object> treeNode = new Tree <Object> ();
```

So, I am really tempting to know the difference between those two: the case when I construct a Node as a different reference of Object types unlikely to the main class's object. Any kind of examples are welcome. Please share your knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you're asking. Are you asking about the difference between `E` and `Object`?

Comment: Yes, quite. I thought E and Object are different from each other but when I use those like on above, it works without an error. Or are "E" and "Object" the same things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between these two constructs isn't consequential until the code needs to be called (externally or not).

In short, the first code will allow for your callers to take advantage of generics, while the second one may not. This is only as far as the `treeNode` field goes.

Assume you were to add a methods for your clients to retrieve tree/objects (completely hypothetical):

First version would be:

```
public class HW3<E> {
    private Tree<E> treeNode = new Tree <E> ();
    public E getNodeData();
```

In the first case, your client can call your code using any generic parameter and not need to cast:

```
MW3<SomeType> hw3 = ...//create instance
SomeType data = hw3.getNodeData();
```

Java knows about this and generics will allow you to avoid casts.

Second version would have to be:

```
public class HW3<E> {
    private Tree<Object> treeNode = new Tree <Object> ();
    public Object getNodeData(); //You would have to do this because the field with data wouldn't know about the generic type
```

Unlike this version that uses generics, if you used an object, your clients would have to cast:

```
MW3<SomeType> hw3 = ...//create instance
SomeType data = (SomeType) hw3.getNodeData();
```

In other words, the `E` type parameter is completely useless in the second example and you should simply not use it.
The example I used assumed your `Tree` type has some generic `get` method...

For more, take a look at generic type implementations, such as `java.util.ArrayList`. The key difference between your snippets is in how you use the type parameter and how you make your callers benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks for all the details. It helped

Answer (score 0):

When we define the generic type at the class level, we're essentially telling the java compiler that we'll be dealing with **a type** in class HW3 which, is not known at the time of definition i.e.

```
public class HW3<E> {
  ...
}
```

but derived based on usage, e.g. when you write

```
 HW3<Integer> myHw3OfIntegers = new HW3<Integer>();
 HW3<String> myHw3OfStrings = new HW3<String>();
```

So you can now see how the above 2 declarations impact the `treeNode` field of the generated objects. The first object `myHw3OfIntegers` will represent a tree of Integers where as the second object `myHw3OfStrings` will represent a tree of Strings.

Comment: oh, I got it. Thanks for the info